# Keysight vs Tektronix: AWG+RT SigAn or VSG+RT Oscilloscope?

Tags: rf, oscilloscope, spectrum-analyzer, radar

I'm evaluating some new RF hardware for one of my university's research labs, for antenna testing. We are between a Keysight vector signal generator and a real-time oscope versus a Tektronix AWG and a real-time signal analyzer. Tektronix is about half the price, but Keysight's software offering is 10x better, and we're leaning that way.

I think the VSG is the better option over the AWG, because we need to generate RF. However, I'm unsure about the oscope vs the signal analyzer. Traditionally, a signal analyzer seems like the right choice. Traditional oscopes can't compete with the bandwidth and speed of a sigan for spectrum analysis, but considering this is a real time oscope, it should be capable of everything the signal analyze can do for sensing RF and performing signal analysis. At least, that's my logic. Can a real-time oscope provide the same spectum and signal analysis as a signal analyzer?

Tek: https://www.tek.com/en/products/spectrum-analyzers/rsa7100b

Keysight: https://www.keysight.com/us/en/product/UXR0254BP/infiniium-uxr-series-oscilloscope-25-ghz-4-channel-1mm-inputs.html

The Keysight unit would have  upgraded memory, and hardware accelerated DDC.
And for what it's worth, there are other RF engineers involved who will make the final decision, but I am trying to understand this the best I can.

Comment: This question look opinion based, but in fact isn't to prevent it from getting close, edit it to make your question toward which type of equipment better suit your cursus. It would help a lot if you give more info on your cursus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you are comparing apple to oranges!

AWG are not at all the same as vector signal generator. So are signal analyzer to oscilloscope!

### Source

If you plan on generating mostly CW and modulation, you are way better off with a VSG. If you want to generate wave like pulse, data content or  others (like triangle wave) you should go with the AWG. AWG definitely aren't as stable and accurate to any proper synthesizer. So if you want some signal purity, it is a no brainer. If you teach low frequency design (like with opamp) AWG is the way to go.

### Analyzer

It depends what you want to teach. If you plan on teaching RF with wave propagation, harmonics and so on, you will be much better with an RF analyzer. If you plan on teaching about low frequency analog design, an oscilloscope would be the right tool. If you plan on teaching on high speed protocols, then the UXR might (probably still overkilled) be the right tool.

### Conclusion

It really depend on your cursus. I don't see how you could ever need such high end equipment to teach any subject. Usually, universities work at lower frequencies with students to be more lenient on mistake. A 25GHz scope doesn't cost the same as a 1GHz to get fix! I did all my cursus with 3GHz equipment and it was plenty to see any phenomena that was need to see. Maybe comment on the specifics you want to teach, but in my opinion, these are all very overkill!

### **Brand**

I'm biased toward Keysight. Tektronix does good test equipment, but until recently, they weren't as performant as the other big name. In high frequency application, you will see a lot more Keysight and Rohde and Schwarz then Tektronix. Both brand are good and take a look at the customer service in your area since they might not be equal. Finally, pricewise, both are similarly priced when they are comparable. So your 10x difference wouldn't be if you took equivalent equipment from Keysight.

### Equivalent solution at Keysight

Just to show you you aren't doing apple to apple comparison, the Keysight equivalent of your Tektronix solution would be probably a N9020B that cost about a tenth of the scope! Either the representative of both companies didn't understood the same needs, but their solutions are very different!

Comment: I appreciate the response. I should clarify, the instruments are for a research lab, and we'll need to operate up to 20 GHz. (Updated my question) The UXR has a built-in 160MHz RTSA, which is significantly smaller bandwidth than the Tek RTSA... I'll take a look at the Keysight SA you linked.

Comment: I think (might be proven wrong) but the video bandwidth of any SA will outperform a DSO FFT. I'd be curious how they perform their RTSA since they could take the MDO domain and use down converters to have a good video bandwidth, but most likely, they will use an FFT.They can be quite fast, even faster then a SA on wideband measurement, but in 0 span, nothing beats a SA! Also, the noise floor of the SA should outperform the oscilloscope quite significantly.